# How To Send Form Data to Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, html, database, forms, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple **HTML** form

**HTML:**

`<form><input type="text id="example"><input type="submit" value="SEND!!" name="data">`

I want the form data in my Firebase Project

Please Help Me

Comment: That'll require you to add the Firebase SDK and write some code, as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write. Also see some of the top results from this search: https://www.google.com/search?q=How+To+Send+Form+Data+to+Firebase+Realtime+Database

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.